# ng-model binding with 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

pls bear with me as I am new to angular js. I have a grid of text input boxes in my view that i wish to map to a 2d array in my controller or the strange equivalent of that in java script. My code in my view is

```
<div ng-repeat="row in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" class="row">
                <div ng-repeat="column in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" class="col-sm-1 no-padding">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="puzzle.board[row][column]" name="cell[]">
                </div>
</div>
```

my controller class uses the following code to initialize the puzzle object

```
    $scope.puzzle = {}; 
    $scope.puzzle.dimensions =9;
    $scope.puzzle.board = [$scope.puzzle.dimensions]
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.puzzle.dimensions; i++) {
            $scope.puzzle.board[i] = [$scope.puzzle.dimensions];
    }
```

However, when i enter a value in the input fields and check the value of cell in the console, it is still showing up as undefined
what am i missing here?

Comment: try putting `{{puzzle.board | json}}` somewhere on your view, will show you the updated object

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/BwA9yy9a8XOWjNP4how1?p=preview

Comment: haha silly me, thanks for the help my indexes in the view began from 1 and the second cell of the board in the controller was getting updated when it should have been the first but the binding was actually working

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
  $scope.puzzle.board = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.puzzle.dimensions; i++) {
    $scope.puzzle.board[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.puzzle.dimensions; j++) {
      $scope.puzzle.board[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
```

and start numbers from 0:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="column in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" class="col-sm-1 no-padding">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="puzzle.board[row][column]" name="cell[]">
    </div>
</div>
```